# How to make a pulley system with a mechanical advantage of 0.5

Tags: mechanical-engineering, experimental-physics, pulleys, building-physics

**Problem**

Hi I was working for an engineering club and we needed to do this as soon as possible:
We wanted to make a pulley system with a mechanical advantage of 0.5

I know that we have to do something with the string angles but I dont know how the pulleys should be oriented

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Please start to use sentences.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a [block-and-tackle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_and_tackle), namely a gun-tackle.

[image] <sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_and_tackle)</sub>

The general trick to determine advantage is how many verticals you have bearing the load (other than the end you are pulling from). Also, it must be a single rope that loops around the block. So, for example, a tackle with an advantage of 4 (or 0.25) is:

[image] <sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_and_tackle)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

When the load moves up and down the angles are going to change so the mechanical advantage will also change.

Another option is to use a winch, the load is attached to a big drum and the other string is attached to a drum half the size.